# How do you use tornado.testing for creating WebSocket unit tests?

Tags: python, unit-testing, asynchronous, websocket, tornado

I'm working on a project that works with tornado's websocket functionality. I see a decent amount of documentation for working with asychronous code, but nothing on how this can be used to create unit tests that work with their WebSocket implementation.

Does `tornado.testing` provide the functionality to do this? If so, could someone provide a brief example of how to make it happen?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://www.tornadoweb.org/documentation/testing.html

Comment: Yeah I saw that page. I could be wrong, but I believe the asynchronous test cases they document there are for regular HTTP requests, not WebSockets.

Comment: It sounds like you want to use a client to actually hit a test server, in which case I think the answer is no, it does not. `tornado.testing` doesn't include a websocket client. You could try something like Selenium.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've attempted to implement some unit tests on `tornado.websocket.WebSocketHandler` based handlers and got the following results:

First of all `AsyncHTTPTestCase` definitely has lack of web sockets support.

Still, one can use it at least to manage `IOLoop` and application stuff which is significant. Unfortunately, there is no WebSocket client provided with tornado, so here enter side-developed library.

Here is [unit test on Web Sockets](https://github.com/dair-targ/tornado-websocket-client/blob/master/test_websocket.py) using Jef Balog's [tornado websocket client](https://github.com/jbalogh/tornado-websocket-client).

Comment: The "Small fix" comment can be removed since it has been merged into the upstream repository mentioned already.

Comment: Tornado does have a Websocket client: tornado.websocket.websocket_connect which instantiates a WebSocketClientConnection object.

Answer (score 19):

As @Vladimir said, you can still use `AsyncHTTPTestCase` to create/manage the test webserver instance, but you **can** still test WebSockets in much the same way as you would normal HTTP requests - there's just no syntactic sugar to help you.

Tornado also has its own WebSocket client so there's no need (as far as I've seen) to use a third party client - perhaps it's a recent addition though. So try something like:

```py
import tornado

class TestWebSockets(tornado.testing.AsyncHTTPTestCase):
    def get_app(self):
        # Required override for AsyncHTTPTestCase, sets up a dummy
        # webserver for this test.
        app = tornado.web.Application([
            (r'/path/to/websocket', MyWebSocketHandler)
        ])
        return app

    @tornado.testing.gen_test
    def test_websocket(self):
        # self.get_http_port() gives us the port of the running test server.
        ws_url = "ws://localhost:" + str(self.get_http_port()) + "/path/to/websocket"
        # We need ws_url so we can feed it into our WebSocket client.
        # ws_url will read (eg) "ws://localhost:56436/path/to/websocket

        ws_client = yield tornado.websocket.websocket_connect(ws_url)

        # Now we can run a test on the WebSocket.
        ws_client.write_message("Hi, I'm sending a message to the server.")
        response = yield ws_client.read_message()
        self.assertEqual(response, "Hi client! This is a response from the server.")
        # ...etc
```

Hopefully that's a good starting point anyway.

Answer (score 1):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15480059/1274789) (and the question) may be of interest, I use [ws4py](http://www.defuze.org/oss/ws4py/docs/#) for the client and Tornado's [AsyncTestCase](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/testing.html) which simplifies the whole thing.

Comment: I would love to see a full example of how to test async websockets in tornado. Do you have a blog post somewhere?

Comment: Hi, no I don't, we have just dropped ws4py for another python module (can't recall it's name right now). We have to do some adjustments due to this change. I will notify you (here) when we have something working again (in a week or two)

Comment: OK, [here](https://www.assembla.com/code/python_websocket_testing/git/nodes) it is. It uses sync web socket requests (for each request we receive a response), but you can make it asynchronous with some modifications. The web socket client library comes from [here](https://github.com/liris/websocket-client/tree/py3) it's for python3, but there's a python2 version as well. b.t.w. there isn't any tornado component (I suppose your intention is to test a tornado server?)

Comment: @Clint You may refer to [my post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32162858/420357) regarding this.