# Tornado unit test with web sockets - what about stack context?

Tags: python, unit-testing, tornado

I've been using tornado server for a while and I have to say I like it.
I have a tornado server (which runs on python3.2) that handles web socket and http requests.
What I want to do is to write some unit tests (which use web sockets) with ws2py (which implements a ws client to use with the tornado IOLoop). I see tornado has the AsyncTestCase class which looks quite interesting especially when used with an AsyncHTTPClient as stated in its [doc](http://www.tornadoweb.org/documentation/testing.html?highlight=asynctestcase#tornado.testing.AsyncTestCase):

```
class MyTestCase2(AsyncTestCase):
    def test_http_fetch(self):
        client = AsyncHTTPClient(self.io_loop)
        client.fetch("http://www.tornadoweb.org/", self.stop)
        response = self.wait()
        # Test contents of response
        self.assertIn("FriendFeed", response.body)
```

I would like to use AsyncTestCase with web sockets,
The client is not a problem, i can send and receive messages without problems.

I guess what I have to do is to pass `self.stop` to the client as callback in order to retrieve the received message by calling `wait()` like in the example above. But somehow this does not work, here is what i have:

```
class SQLRequests(AsyncTestCase):
    """Tests sql requests"""

    def test_sql_req_1(self):
        """first test function"""
        client = AsyncWSClient(httpBaseUrl, self.io_loop)
        client.sendMessage('some_message', self.stop)

        response = self.wait()
        if response.data:
            print('got %s' % str(response.data))
            # some test
            self.assertTrue(True)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

This is my web socket client:

```
class AsyncWSClient(TornadoWebSocketClient):
"""
Asynchronous web socket client based on ws4py's tornadoclient
Sends a message and calls callback with received message
"""
def __init__(self, url, ioLoop=None, **kwargs):
    TornadoWebSocketClient.__init__(self, url, io_loop=ioLoop, **kwargs)
    self._callback = None
    self._message = None

def opened(self):
    """called when web socket opened"""
    self.send(self._message, binary=False)      

def received_message(self, message):
    """Received a message"""
            self.close()
    if self._callback:
        self._callback(message)

def sendMessage(self, message, callback):
    """Connects and sends message when connected"""
    self._message = message
    self._callback = callback
    self.connect()
```

I do receive a `ws2py.messaging.TextMessage` object as response, but its data field it `None` although some data has been received by the client. If I have a look into the AsyncTestCase, before it calls the callback, that object has some data in it, which disappears somewhere somehow when it is passed as return value of wait().

I see there is a mystical thing in tornado called stack_context, has that something to do with my problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that the message "data" is contained in the `data` attribute of `message`. Once `received_message` is called, `message.data` is reset to None (https://github.com/Lawouach/WebSocket-for-Python/blob/master/ws4py/websocket.py#L369).

So, just call your callback passing `message.data` rather than the full `message`. Like that:

```
def received_message(self, message):
    """Received a message"""
    self.close()
    if self._callback:
       self._callback(message.data)
```

Comment: It works, many thanks!! I can't remember what I was doing exactly, but it prints out the message.